# When the lib is in /lib : usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<Mylibrary>

Tags: linux, gcc

I copy on the folder `/lib`: `-llibpxisw32s.so.3.8.0`

I created a virtual link:

```
ln -s libpxisw32s.so.3.8.0 libpxisw32s.so
```

And then compile:

```
gcc pilpxswTest.c -l/pxisw32s.so  

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find
-l/pxisw32s.so collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: why not try `-l/lib/pxisw32s.so`

Comment: Thank you for your answer HuStmpHrrr but is not working

Comment: oh gee, i was wrong. for sure it's not working. it's a shared object. it should be dynamically linked not statically.

Comment: What version in the library? Note the error: `usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpxisw32s.so.3.8.0` It is looking for a library with soname .3.8.0. Does your file match? In `/lib/` try `ln -s pxisw32s.so libpxisw32s.so.3.8.0` They try with `gcc pilpxswTest.c -lpxisw32s.so`

Comment: Hi David, I already try this : ln -s pxisw32s.so libpxisw32s.so.3.8.0 They try with gcc pilpxswTest.c -lpxisw32s.so. But the compiler still give me the same error.

Comment: I think your naming convention is backwards. Usually the library is named `libpxisw32s.so.3.8.0` and then you will have links `libpxisw32s.so` and say `libpxisw32s.so.1`. What I would try is `mv /lib/pxisw32s.so /lib/libpxisw32s.so.3.8.0`, then `ls -s ibpxisw32s.so.3.8.0 libxisw32s.so` and then compile. (and leave the `.so` off the end in your `gcc` command - per the answer)

Comment: I upgrade the question. I notice I made a mistake in my explanation sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your value for the `-l` option is still wrong (see my answer). It should be `-lpxisw32s`.

Comment: @fdjamby Have a look at GCC's `-L` option.

Comment: It's now working gcc pilpxswTest.c -lpxisw32s. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted one if it solved your problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically link a shared object library named `libpxisw32s.so`, your command line option should be `-lpxisw32s`. `gcc` takes the argument and looks for a filename named `lib<libraryname>.so` in your library search path.

It also sounds like you might have some goofy symlinks causing confusion. Check out how `libz` does it for a good example:

```
libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.3
libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
libz.so.1.2.3
```